# How can I make SKSpriteNode positions the same for any simulator/device?

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, xcode7, skspritenode

In my game, the position of my SKNodes slightly change when I run the App on a virtual simulator vs on a real device(my iPad).

Here are pictures of what I am talking about.

[This is the virtual simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBQyT.png)

[This is my Ipad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNs9s.jpg)

It is hard to see, but the two red boxes are slightly higher on my iPad than in the simulator

Here is how i declare the size and position of the red boxes and green net:
The following code is located in my GameScene.swift file

```
func loadAppearance_Rim1() {                                                
Rim1 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake((frame.size.width) / 40, (frame.size.width) / 40))
Rim1.position = CGPointMake(((frame.size.width) / 2.23), ((frame.size.height) / 1.33))          
Rim1.zPosition = 1                                                      
addChild(Rim1)                                                          
}

func loadAppearance_Rim2(){                                                
    Rim2 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake((frame.size.width) / 40, (frame.size.width) / 40))
    Rim2.position = CGPoint(x:  ((frame.size.width) / 1.8), y: ((frame.size.height) / 1.33))                                                                                                    
    Rim2.zPosition = 1                                                      
    addChild(Rim2)                                                        
}
func loadAppearance_RimNet(){                                        
    RimNet = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), size: CGSizeMake((frame.size.width) / 7.5, (frame.size.width) / 150))
    RimNet.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width / 1.99, frame.size.height / 1.33)
    RimNet.zPosition = 1                                                    
    addChild(RimNet)                                                        
}
func addBackground(){
    //background
    background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
    background.zPosition = 0
    background.size = self.frame.size
    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
    self.addChild(background)
}
```

Additionally my GameViewController.swift looks like this

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

var scene: GameScene!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Configure the view
    let skView = view as! SKView
    //If finger is on iphone, you cant tap again
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false

    //Create and configure the scene
    //create scene within size of skview
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
    //scene.anchorPoint = CGPointZero

    //present the scene
    skView.presentScene(scene)



}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .Landscape
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

How can I make the positions of my nodes be the same for each simulator/physical device?

Comment: @Darvydas this question is very similar to the once you answered in this stack overflow post "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787770/how-to-scale-position-nodes-swift-spritekit-custom-view"

Could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Maybe this problem has to do with the way I am setting the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making a Universal application you need to declare the size of the scene using integer values. Here is an example:

```
scene = GameScene(size:CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536))
```

Then when you initialize the positions and sizes of your nodes using CGPoint and CGSize, make them dependant on SKScene size. Here is an example:

```
node.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2)
```

If you declare the size of the scene for a Universal App like this:

```
scene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

then your SKSpriteNode positions will be all messed up. You may also need to change the scaleMode to .ResizeFill. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should round those floating point values to integers via a call to (int)round(float) so that the values snap to whole pixels. Any place where you use CGPoint or CGSize should use whole pixels as opposed to floating point values.

Comment: If I use an integer value instead of a float won't the positioning of the Node not be as exact as I need?


Also I am not sure exactly how to implement this in my code.


Is there a way to round the floating point value in same line that I am declaring the position?
@MoDJ

Comment: Please take some time to understand pixels and how points map to pixels in iOS and SpriteKit: http://math.hws.edu/graphicsbook/c2/s1.html

Comment: After taking some time to understand that I think I need to implement anchor points for each SKSpriteNode @MoDJ

Comment: This does not fix the problem. If i use integers as parameters for CGPoint(40, 40) the SKNode is still not at the same position on my iPad vs simulator